# How deserialize Byte array to object - Windows 8 / WP 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-store-apps, arrays, deserialization

Hi I use code below to convert object to byte array now I need this byte array convert back to object. Does any one know how to deserialize this in windows 8 app? I find some code but use **Serialize** and **BinaryReader** classes and this classes are not in windows 8 or does not know it.

```
Person ps = new Person();
        ps.name = "Lucy";

        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Dictionary<String, String>>));

        byte[] byteArr;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, ps.name);
            byteArr = ms.ToArray();
        }
        tbByteResult.Text = byteArr.ToString();
```

Comment: It seem you are supossed to serialize/deserialize an object of type `List<Dictionary<String, String>>` but you are acually serializing a `string`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```cs
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArr))
    {
        var yourObject = serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
```