# How to store and retrieve Chromium Web Browser object

Tags: c#, history, cefsharp

I'm developing an application using `cefSharp`, all is good now i need to maintain history for all browser tabs opened and closed by user and providing a option for opening closed tabs.

Is there a way to store Chromium Web Browser object into memory or database and retrieve it from there.
I've used below code to store objects into database

```
var objBrowserTest = (ChromiumWebBrowser)browserControl;

MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(memStream);
sw.Write(objBrowserTest);

string sql = @"
INSERT INTO tblBrowserObj(cromObj)
VALUES(@VarBinary);
SELECT @@identity";

string connectionstring;
connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    objConn.Close();
}
objConn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, objConn);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@VarBinary", SqlDbType.VarBinary, Int32.MaxValue);
sqlCmd.Parameters["@VarBinary"].Value = memStream.GetBuffer();
string strID = sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    objConn.Close();
}
```

## Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblBrowserObj](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cromObj] [varbinary](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My problem is that the `memStream.GetBuffer()` always shows `byte[0]`.

Can any one tell me how can i store and retrieve Chromium Web Browser object from memory or database, or is there another way to do this type of stuff.

Comment: If your interested in `history` then you could implement https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1503

Comment: Can you elaborate it some more.

Comment: Read the documentation that's linked in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## 1 - Read/Write from memory

From [Writing to then reading from a MemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232443/writing-to-then-reading-from-a-memorystream) I extract some steps you should follow:

1. Don't forget to flush after `sw.Write(objBrowserTest);`
2. You have to reset the position of the stream with `memStream.Position = 0;` before read.
3. Wrap the stream with a **StreamWriter** and use the `ReadToEnd()` method to read all bytes of the stream.

Don't use `GetBuffer()`, it doesn't get the content of the stream, it takes the buffer of a buffered stream.

## 2 - Read/Write an Object from Byte[]

When you want to serialeze and object you have 2 classes to do it `DataContractSerializer` (DCS) and `BinaryFormatter` (BF).

### 2.1 - Serialize

When you want to serialize to a `byte[]` you can use the DCS 'WriteObtect' or the BF 'Serialize'. Both methods uses an stream (your memory stream) and an object.

### 2.2 - Deserialize

To deserialize an stored `byte[]` from it, you can use the DCS `ReadObject` and BF `Deserialize` (casting to the class). Both methods argument is the Stream to read from.

## What you need to do

1. Serialize with one
2. Use the `memStream.ToArray()` to get the `byte[]` to store it.
3. When retrieving, use a a memory stream to write the array

#### Tips

Use the `MemoryStream` constructor with a `byte[]` argument and then `Position = 0`.

This code maybe helps you:

```
public byte[] ObjectToBytes(Object obj)
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(memStream, obj);

            return memStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }  // do what you want

    return null;
}

public T BytesToObject<T>(byte[] array) where T : class
{
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(array) { Position = 0 })
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            T obj = formatter.Deserialize(memStream) as T;

            return obj;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }  // do what you want

    return null;
}
```

Simply use `sqlCmd.Parameters["@VarBinary"].Value = ObjectToBytes(objBrowserTest );` and when retrieving use `BytesToObject<ChromiumWebBrowser>(bytes);`

#### Sources

http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Byte-array-to-object.html

[How deserialize Byte array to object - Windows 8 / WP 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671702/how-deserialize-byte-array-to-object-windows-8-wp-8)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: After adding `sw.Flush();memStream.Position = 0;` it is working fine. but now i'm unable to convert it back to the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information, but my object is a non-serializable object.

Comment: Then you can use a ISerializableSurrogate. More Info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166105/is-it-possible-to-do-net-binary-serialization-of-an-object-when-you-dont-have